# Convert usual char* from to cli array

Tags: .net, arrays, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm using C++ CLI. I need to convert usual char * to cli array. Here is what exactly I want :

```
unsigned char * b1 = (unsigned char *) &xp0[0];
unsigned char * b2 = (unsigned char *) &xp2[0];
unsigned char * b3 = (unsigned char *) &xp1[0];

array<byte>^ a1 = gcnew array<byte>(928); //a1 = b1;
array<byte>^ a2 = gcnew array<byte>(928); //a2 = b2;
array<byte>^ a3 = gcnew array<byte>(232); //a3 = b3;

//FBOI::Lambda::SetP(numSF,a1,a2,a3);
```

What is the easiest way to convert char * to cli byte array with single dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Marshal::Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) like:

`Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(source_addr ), dest_array, start_index, length);`

```
Marshal::Copy(IntPtr( b1 ), a1, 0, a1->Length);
```